# I would like to add HTML elements to the exupero's saveSvgAsPng functions

Tags: javascript, html, svg, download, png

I have a project in which an SVG element is drawn in the shape of a radar chart. Next to the radar chart there are HTML tables with calculated numbers. Both elements are presented on a certain page. I need a download button which will download a PNG file where both elements are visable.

At this point in time i have this download button, and it will download the SVG element as is. The browser will automatically download the PNG file and on this PNG file the radar chart is fully visable. This works trough exupero's saveSvgAsPng function, which can be found here:

> https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng

This works quite well. It will instantly download the SVG image. I invoke this function by the following code:

```
$('#cmd').click(function () {

    saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0], "filename.png", {scale: 2, backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"});
});
```

There are more functions i could use, for example:

```
svgAsDataUri, which will create a promise
```

and

```
svgAsPngUri which also creates a promise
```

The problem is, i have no idea how to work with promises. I figured i could use those promises to get the SVG radarchart, get the HTML elements and put them together in a PNG file which will be downloaded by the browser, but have no idea how to do it.

Is anyone able to help me to get both the SVG and the HTML elements on 1 PNG file?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. What you need to do is to create a canvas for each element. In my case i created 2, 1 for the chart and 1 for the HTML tables. Then you combine the 2 on a seperate canvas which can be downlaoded. In code it did the following:

HTML

```
<img style="display:none"/>
<canvas style="display:none" id="canvas1" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<canvas style="display:none" style="background-color:white;" id="canvas3" width="1920" height="2500"></canvas>
```

The img will contain an SVG element.

Then in javascript draw the SVG on the IMG tag and after that draw the chart also in canvas where the 2 will be combined

```
//get elements which will be used to write chart on canvas
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var img = document.querySelector('img');
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

    // get svg data
    var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

    // make it base64
    var svg64 = btoa(xml);
    var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';

    // prepend a "header"
    var image64 = b64Start + svg64;

    // set it as the source of the img element
    img.src = image64;

    //connect img to arm
    var arm = img;

    //wait for the image to be drawn and then draw it on canvas
    arm.addEventListener('load', function(){
        //draw on canvas
        canvas3.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 50, 400, 1100, 800);

    });
```

Then you need to draw the HTML elements on canvas2 and after that add it to the canvas where the chart has already been drawn, canvas3. Then when this is done canvas 3 will contain both canvas1 and canvas2. Then make it available for download.

```
//draw the tables on canvas
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
        //set id to canvas2
        canvas.id = "canvas2";
        //draw the tables on the canvas
        canvas3.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 1700, 2500);
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3");
        //convert to jpg
        var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        //make it ready for download
        downloadURI(img, "file.jpg");

    });
```